# How can I reverse the history numbering?

Tags: zsh

I am a unix addict, and many of the machines I use (at home and at work) are now quickly passing the 10,000 command mark. I like to keep all of the commands I issue readily available which is why I have set the upper limit to something like 100,000 entries, but it is becoming tedious to recall particular recent entries as I have to be writing `!12524` in the shell to expand out that one.

Sure, I can use the shortcut ones to recall the last command or even the tenth-last command but its impossible to keep track of that so 90% of the time I am doing things like `history | grep 'configure --prefix'` (for reviewing how I configured something last, etc) and then using whatever history index that spits back.

Can I reverse it so that command #10000 corresponds to the command from ten thousand commands ago, and have command #1 be the last command?

Comment: also i'll mention that a non zsh solution is not fully adequate as the expansion of stuff `!12524` for instance can be expanded out by pressing tab, which is something that helps a lot. And I believe there are more crazy fun things that can be done to expand out only the last arg, or expand all but the first arg, etc. which i'd like to commit to memory someday.

Comment: I'm fairly sure there's no builtin method of doing this. Conceivably, you could write a script to re-order `~/.zsh_history` during `preexec`, but I could see that being messy to implement without clobbering the history. Do you use `HIST_IGNORE_DUPS`? You've probably also got many commands in history which you don't care about (variants on `cd ..`, for example) - a custom `cull_history()` function could clean a bit without affecting the commands you use daily.

Comment: Another option you could consider is better history-searching-and-rerunning. Grabbing the command entry number from `history | grep foo`, then rerunning the command wouldn't be hard to wrap in a function. [I'm not sure what history searching capabilities `zsh` has; it's on the to-do list for my learning].

Comment: Is there some reason you aren't just using history completion?  Check out [this article](http://www.techrepublic.com/blog/opensource/enhanced-history-searching-in-zsh/1347) for some helpful key bindings to use up and down arrows.